# Движение в 2Д игре по сетке(grid)

Tags: 2d

Как прототип.

Есть поле 10 на 10

```
for row in range(10):   
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(10):
        grid[row].append("что-то")
```

Моя цель создать бездумно бродящую иишку по карте(если можно подскажите толковые статьи)
Но возникли вопросы.
До меня дошло что перемещение получается копирование всех данных ГГ или НИП из одной ячейки массива в следующую ячейку.   (это вообще нормально?)

1. Python хорошо подходит для таких задач? так как планируется большое количество НИП(500-1000). Просто не хочу чтоб в конечном итоге двигалось с 1 фпс.
2. Не могу сформировать в голове осознание как экземпляр прототипа двигается.
3. Или можно как-то чтоб в ячейке была ссылка на объект, и просто менять позицию указателя, или вовсе менять положение в самом экземпляре а он при обновление экрана сам какбы передвинет визуально.

P.S. прототип делаю на pygame, по крайне мере пока.

Comment: Дайте ГГ координаты (X, Y) и рисуйте его поверх поля. И ничего не надо будет никуда копировать.

Comment: Тогда будет куда сложней выполнять взаимодействие с окружением, и другими персонажами. И ГГ там не будет, в перспективе это как муровейник(а потом может и будет).